# How do I solve MMUMapper error?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm new to Android App development.

I am implementing GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) in my application.

When I try to post the value to my URL, I get an error:

```
the Stack Trace Error and MMUMapper Error, fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5) and invalid operation for Unregister MVA with VA.
```

Does anyone have a solution? Kindly help me.

Comment: Would probably be beneficial to see some more information besides the error message itself.

Comment: Hi pglynn and Rilcon, very thankful for your response, But Sorry Presently don't have the code due to shifted the company.But remember the scenario, when i updated the Android SDK and java, I faced this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it is memory management unit related error. While you work with GCM make sure to increase your app memory and -vmargs in your eclipse.ini file. And if you used play services jar you should be using it with Proguard.